# Using more then one service with multiple nameservers?

Tags: nameserver

I purchased a domain from Namecheap and migrated it to a host at Hostinger.
With the following server names: ns1.hostinger.se, ns2.hostinger.se, ns3.hostinger.se ,ns4.hostinger.se.

However, I want to have CloudFlare enabled on my website as well. When I set up my domain on Cloudflare it wants me to change from hostinger nameservers to mary.ns.cloudflare.com, terin.ns.cloudflare.com. So my question is it possible to have more than one server name set at one time even though CloudFlare says it should be removed since I want to use CloudFlare and hostinger however my domain is registered on Namecheap?

[Multiple nameservers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEfBq.png)

Is this allowed or will it cause an error or confusion between the name servers?

Comment: For Cloudflare's CDN and DDOS protection to work, you must use Cloudflare's nameservers and manage your DNS through them.

Comment: @ceejayoz So then I will need to set up a DNS from Cloudflare to Hostinger?

Comment: You'll want to copy over your records from Hostinger. After that you won't be using their nameservers at all.

Comment: @ceejayoz I pointed the CloudFlare CDN and edited the DNS to Hostinger would that work? Cloudflare DNS: https://puu.sh/vpkFB/5ac0a8ac66.PNG and Hostinger info: https://puu.sh/vpkGU/5d629cd33e.PNG

Comment: You'll probably want to turn off Cloudflare's proxy for the webmail/cpanel stuff (IIRC you can do it by clicking the orange cloud to turn it grey), and you need to migrate the MX record (and the `ftp` A record).

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this before. If you run Cloudflare nameservers alongside any other name servers you will experience random/intermittent errors.

Why do you want multiple nameservers? Cloudflare's name servers are some of the fastest and most reliable available today.

If multiple nameservers is a requirement you may need to use something else as your DNS/CDN for this project

Answer (score 1):

No, that won't work.

Cloudflare's name servers work by replacing your A (and AAAA) records with IP addresses pointing to Cloudflare servers, which then forward requests to the IP addresses you configured. If you don't use Cloudflare's nameservers, requests to your web site will never be routed through them.

Using a combination of Cloudflare's nameservers and Hostinger's nameservers is even worse. This configuration will mean that requests will randomly be routed either through Cloudflare or directly to your web host, depending on which nameserver was used.

If you want to use Cloudflare, you must use their nameservers, and *only* their nameservers.

Answer (score 1):

It would work perfectly fine **if** you had the same zone data on all the nameservers (typically achieved with `AXFR`/`IXFR`).
The reason why this is important is simple, you have no control over which one of your nameservers will receive any given query.

It's actually, generally speaking, a good idea to hedge your bets by using multiple independent service providers instead of just one.

The problem here is that the Cloudflare specific features (presumably the reason for the question) cannot really be replicated at other nameservers (records generated dynamically based on configuration and state of their infrastructure, etc).

So, generally yes, for this scenario probably no.